# int cannot be converted to String in showConfirmDialog using JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to run the following piece of code in the main Java class:

```
personName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the person  !");

            onepty.setNameOfPerson(personName);


            SpeechDecision = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                 "Select Yes or No", "choose one", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
            onepty.speechCheck(speechDecision);
```

The following method is defined in a data definition class which I am accessing via `onepty` object as shown above:

```
      public String speechCheck(String str){

         if(str == "Yes" || str =="YES"||str == "Y" ||str== "y"||str=="YEs"||str=="yeS"||str=="yES"){
            this.speechVar = str;

         }


         else {

         this.speechVar = str;

         }

      }
```

But I am getting the following error after compiling using jGrasp :

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
            speechDecision = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                                          ^
1 error
```

Although the error is self explanatory but since I am net to jOptionPane, I am wondering whether the button input selected by the user after clicking on Yes or No option is getting stored as integer rather than string? Do I need to modify my `speechCheck` method to catch Integer value?Please advise.

Comment: Seriously now, you are using == to compare strings ?!

Comment: `showConfirmDialog` return type `int` not `String`.

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't show the declaration of `speechDecision`. And yes, the `showConfirmDialog` method returns `int`, as you could easily have verified with the documentation. Btw, don't compare strings like that. See http://tinyurl.com/so-java-string-equality

Comment: Yes, `speechDecision` is a string variable. Since return type is `int` , my `speechCheck` method is of no use I believe

Comment: the word of the day is 'equalsIgnoreCase' and it would reduce your code to almost half what it is now. Check what parameters are expected, and what you are passing.

Comment: So, What integer value is returned for Yes or No option ?

Comment: you might want to use if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("y") to avoid long if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `SpeechDecision` is probably String, and it should be an `int` since that's the returned value from [`showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-), see its signature:

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(...)
              ↑
```

Few notes:

- Follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- Don't compare String using `==`, use `equals` instead
- Indent your code for better world

Comment: Could you tell me what integer value is returned for Yes or No selection?

Comment: @John See the linked documentation please.

Comment: I saw the following in the doc `Returns:
an int indicating the option selected by the user` . However, I am still not sure what integer value will be returned when a user will select Yes or No. Based on that I am thinking of modifying my method.

Comment: @John It's `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` or `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`

Comment: I tried to print out the value using the following : `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                     "Speech Check " + speechDecision ,
                      "This is The Title",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
` and I saw that for Yes I am getting `0` and `1` for selecting No.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
  int speechDecision = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title,     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  if (speechDecision == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  {
      // Do something here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JOptionPane default constants
JOptionPane.YES_OPTION for YES and
JOptionPane.NO_OPTION for NO 
and the type of SpeechDecision Should be integer.

So, Code will look like,

```
int speechDecision = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Select Yes No",  "choose one", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (speechDecision == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
      // Do something here for yes
}
else{
      // Do something here for no
}
```